# What does ExcelColName() return in VB?

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am trying to understand how to import data from SQL and then export it to excel. I came across this function ExcelColName(). What does it return exactly ? Does it return cells like B1, A1 ?

```
xlRange = xlwsGroup.Range("A1", ExcelColName(childColCount) & 2)
```

Let us expect the value of childColCount to be 12. What does ExcelColName(12) & 2 return ?

Comment: Click on the function in VBE then press Shift+F2

Comment: That's a function that someone has developed. My guess is it returns the letter of a column, such as "L" in the case of childColCount = 12.

Comment: It is a user-defined function: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/26303/export-data-to-excel-much-faster